# Angular Application Offline

Tags: angularjs, html5-appcache, offlineapps

I would like to improve my angular application to work offline. I wanted to use App cache, but right now it's deprecated and the Service Workers is an experimental technology. What should I use? Any suggestions?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App cache is announced as deprecated but most of the major browsers support it till date (please see caniuse.com). I think you can implement app cache for now and once service workers matures, you can slowly migrate the resource caching to service workers.